# Is it possible to get within service other applications names that are in foreground?

Tags: android, foreground, background-service

E.g.

There is some service that is working in background and it gets the name of app i'll open. For instance, i open Tetris - service gets Tetris, then i'll open Calculator - service gets Calculator....

Comment: I believe it works the other way around -- the app binds to the service.

Comment: i think the OP is looking for a task manager (windows) equivalent in android?